# Create method to dynamically determine which UICollectionViewCell is in the center of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently working on an Objective-C iOS application that features Scene with a full screen Collection View with cells almost the size of the entire screen that scroll vertically down the Scene.

I want to be able to programmatically change the cell in this Collection View that is at the center of the visible screen and the way that I am currently achieving this functionality is by waiting for the scrolling to stop on the Collection View, and then editing whatever cell is positioned at the very center of the screen as seen in the method below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath =
    [self.collectionViewFollwersFeed indexPathForItemAtPoint:
     [self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.collectionViewFollwersFeed]];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell;
    NSString *CellIdentifier;

    CellIdentifier = @"FollowersFeed";
    cell = [_collectionViewFollwersFeed cellForItemAtIndexPath:centerCellIndexPath];

    //edit cell here

}
```

While this method of accomplishing this functionality works to a certain extent, the changes to the cell only begin when the user stops scrolling.

I want to be able to start making changes to the center cell the moment that a new cell is covering the center position, without having to stop scrolling.  How could I edit this method so that if and only if a new cell is covering the center position of the screen, then this method should be called?

Comment: How about scrollViewDidScroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't agree more with my educated peer [dahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh).

Having said that, you might want to actually animate something according to the scroll position and not just "change" cell when it hits the center...

To do that you could have the cell track its own position:

Pass the scrollview to the cell on instantiation:

```
// MyCollectionView's DataSource

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.observedScrollView = theScrollViewYouWantToTrack;
    [cell startObservingPosition];
    return cell;
}
```

Make sure the cell holds the `observedScrollView` weakly, to avoid a retain cycle

Then in your cell's .m file register a KVO observer:

```
// MyCollectionViewCell.m

- (void)startObservingPosition {
   if (self.observedScrollView) {
      [self.observedScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:NULL];
   }
}
```

Make sure to remove the KVO observer before the cell deallocates... or else crash! you can also consider using a nice [enhanced KVO observer](https://github.com/Noambaron/NBPoliteObserver) I built that releases itself automatically

Every time the KVO Observer fires (when scrollView scrolls) - you can figure out the position and react accordingly.

This example shows how to detect when cell is in center, but also illustrates how you can do so much more:

```
// MyCollectionViewCell.m

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {
      if (self.observedScrollView) {  
         CGPoint offset = self.observedScrollView.contentOffset;
         CGRect contentViewRect = [self.contentView convertRect:self.contentView.bounds toView:self.observedScrollView];
         CGFloat contentViewCenterY = contentViewRect.origin.y + contentView.size.height * 0.5 - offset.y;
         if (contentViewCenterY == self.observedScrollView.bounds.height * 0.5) {
            // the contentView is in the center of the viewable feed. do your animations...
         }  
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing a cell == yuck.  Changing the model == nice.

So add an NSInteger to the datasource like `indexOverCenter`.  Initialize it to something invalid, like -1.  Then, in the delegate, detect the condition:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath =
    [self.collectionViewFollwersFeed indexPathForItemAtPoint:
     [self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.collectionViewFollwersFeed]];

    self.indexOverCenter = centerCellIndexPath.row;
    // don't edit the cell here:  yuck
    // reload it:  nice
    [self.collectionViewFollwersFeed reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[ centerCellIndexPath ]];
}
```

Do your "editing" work in cellForItemAtIndex, comparing the passed indePath row to indexOverCenter.  If they are equal, then do your special formatting there.

Answer (score 0):

In my CollectionView I have derived it like this:

```
private func findCenterIndex() -> Int {
        let center = self.view.convert(numberCollectionView.center, to: self.numberCollectionView)
        let row = numberCollectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: center)?.row


        guard let index = row else {

            return 0
        }


        self.rating = index

        return index

    }
```

So you can easily convert it to your objective-c code